# Write XML file to URL in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to write data to XML file in xcode.

Say the XML file resides in http://www.abcd.com/sample.xml, i want to write data into that.

sample.xml

```
<Candidate>
<name>John Doe</name>
</Candidate>
```

I want to overwrite John Doe to something else.

All i know is i can pass NSURLString the URL & am very new to this technology, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to parse the xml in/out.
For a test scenario you can do this:

```
    NSString *theName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nameField.text]; //I guess you know you should put a textfield there
    NSMutableArray *overviewInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [overviewInfo addObject:theName];

    [overviewInfo writeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://username:password@abcd.com/sample.xml"]];
    //username is your username on server
    //password is your password on server
    //example.com is the rest of the address you want to put that on
```

Hope that works for you.